# PHP form send email to multiple recipients

Tags: php, forms, email

I have some PHP code that I'm using to send a form off to a specific e-mail address. However, I'd like to include a couple more e-mail addresses in the PHP for when it sends it. How can I do that?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@email.com";
    $email_subject = "MVP Nomination";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['username']) ||
        !isset($_POST['body'])||
        !isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $username = $_POST['username']; // required
    $body = $_POST['body']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];         // required

  $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$username)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Username you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($username)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($body)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
}
header("Location: ThankYou.html");  //Redirect to Thank You HTML page after email is sent
?>​
```

Thank you.

Comment: @PLB - StackOverflow's code features are perfect for this. There is no reason to use an external site.

Comment: Did you try searching before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+multiple+email+addresses+

Comment: @Buggabill No, he has posted on jsfiddle php code, that's why I've suggested using viper-7. Question is edited now.

Comment: Yep... It know it has been edited. I edited it.  Relying on an external site is not good practice.  Links can die - including on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This will work:

```
$email_to = "jhewitt@amleo.com,some@other.com,yet@another.net";
```

Comment: Other answers I have seen put a space between the emails after the comma.  This is the only one I have seen without.  I figure this is better?  Are there differences between the 2 ways?

Comment: how to hide other emails in header.it will show all the email addresses to receiver email address

Comment: @smehsoud this is a different question but you can simply add a BCC line to the header.

Answer (score 13):

Use comma separated values as below.

```
$email_to = 'Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

or run a foreach for email address

```
//list of emails in array format and each one will see their own to email address
$arrEmail = array('Mary <mary@example.com>', 'Kelly <kelly@example.com>');

foreach($arrEmail as $key => $email_to)
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you need to add emails as CC or BCC, add the following part in the variable you use as for your header :

```
$headers .= "CC: sombodyelse@noplace.com".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "BCC: hidden@special.com".PHP_EOL;
```

Regards

Comment: For optimal cross-platform compatibility, you may wish to use PHP_EOL instead of \r\n.

Comment: I have changed the `\r\n` by `PHP_EOL` as Evan Donovan truely noticed.

Answer (score 5):

You can add your receipients to `$email_to` variable separating them with comma (`,`). Or you can add new fields to headers, namely `CC:` or `BCC:` and put your receipients there. `BCC` is most recommended

Answer (score 3):

If i understood correct try this one

```
$headers = "Bcc: someone@domain.com";
```

or

```
$headers = "Cc: someone@domain.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

If these all answers are not working then You can simply use multiple mail function for multiple recipient.

```
$email_to1 = "firstEmail@demo.com";
$email_to2 = "secondEmail@demo.com";

mail($email_to1, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
mail($email_to2, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you concatenate the multiple emails with ',' instead of ';'

Answer (score 0):

Also if your email addresses are stored in an array:

```
$emails = ['jhewitt@amleo.com', 'some@other.com', 'yet@another.net'];
$email_to = implode(',', $emails); // "glue" every array elements (emails) with a comma and return a single string "jhewitt@amleo.com,some@other.com,yet@another.net"
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

This can be useful when you retrieve email addresses from an external data source.

Answer (score 0):

the `$email_to` of the php **mail** can accept multiple email recipients.

you can use `implode` to your different email to concatenate them using comma '`,`'

if you are using **phpmailer** you can use `explode` to separate your string of email address then add them using loop like for each

```
/** separate each email address */
           $str_arr = explode (",", $recipient);

/** add each email address using addAddress */
           foreach ($str_arr as $email) {
            $mail->addAddress($email); //(recipientEmail, recipientName) - name is optional
            }
```

it will then look like this when sent

[image]