# PHP mail will only send with two recipients

Tags: php, apache, email

Using the PHP mail() function on a server for a client

When i do:

```
mail("name@domain.com",$sub,$body,$head);
```

It fails (returns nothing and is not sent)
But if i do:

```
mail("name@domain.com,x",$sub,$body,$head);
```

it works fine

I currently have it set up to this, just so my client can actually do work

```
 mail("name@domain.com,no-reply@domain.com",$sub,$body,$head);
```

which is not a great solution, any ideas?

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with the mail server...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP form send email to multiple recipients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708997/php-form-send-email-to-multiple-recipients)

Comment: thats a weird issue. try by assigning a `$to` variable-
`$to = "name@domain.com"; mail($to,$sub,$body,$head);`

Comment: @Deena this isnt the same problem as that

Comment: @mohit ive tried many things like that, tried removing the "," using an explode(), it will only send if a , is in that parameter

Answer (score 0):

If your second senario works fine then in that case you can use

```
  $receivers = array(
                "name@domain.com",
               "no-reply@domain.com"
              ); 

  foreach ($receivers as $receiver) {
   // to send email one by one to the recipients
   mail("$receiver,x",$sub,$body,$head);

  }

?>
```

Comment: yes but the x is the problem
it will show up on everyones email as it going to name@domain.com,x@myhost.com

I only want it to send to 1 email, also i dont think its good sending an email to a dead address pointing to my hosts domain