# PHP Contact Form - Sending email to multiple recipients

Tags: php, html, forms, email

How would I go about making this form able to send to multiple recipients? At the moment it's only allowing me to send it to 1 email only, and when I try typing multiple in (e.g "user1@example.com, user2@example.com") it returns the message for when it's invalid. What do I need to do to fix this?

EDIT: The user has to input the email address it wants to sent to, but it only works with 1, which is why I'm asking for help on how I can edit the code to work with multiple emails/recipients and to be separated with a comma and space.

Here is the code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {




$email_to = array($_GET["celebrant_emails"]);

$email_subject = "Email from website Contact Form";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the email you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go <a href='http://celebrantsaustralia.asn.au/celebrants-trial.htm'>back</a> and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments']) ||

    !isset($_POST['celebrant_emails'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the email you submitted.');       

}



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$celebrant_emails = $_POST['celebrant_emails']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'The Message you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$celebrant_emails)) {

$error_message .= 'The Celebrant Email(s) you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Email details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email sent!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <b>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you shortly.</b>
        <p>(Page will auto-direct in a moment, if it doesn't click <a href="http://website.com">here</a>)</p>
    </body>

</html>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Oh and I'm having it so the user puts the email(s) into the textbox.

Comment: You're best to rethink this, because your code will be open to and considered as spamming/phishing, if this isn't to be used internally. Someone could enter any email address they want, then potentially you'd end up being on server blacklists.

Comment: There is going to be a captcha. It's for this website http://www.celebrantsaustralia.asn.au/celebrants-trial.htm

Comment: Either way Ryan, if you go ahead with this project, you may get into some serious Spam law trouble. As I said; anyone could enter any email they want in your form and sending it off to their known emails. Real spammers could enter their email and phish "you" out. I'm trying to save you from potential disaster.

Comment: Well I'm just doing what these people are telling me to do, plus having a recaptcha will help.

Comment: who are "these people", your client? Even with a recaptcha, that won't stop anyone from entering any email they want.

Comment: what I suggest you "suggest them" to do, is you setup either a dropdown menu with multiple selections or checkboxes, then run a `foreach` and implode on a comma separated array, with the emails hidden away in PHP. I'm thinking they want something of that nature, to send to multiple recipients of their website contacts, correct? Seeing all those photos and linked to email addresses, you could even use jQuery to click on any of them (acting as checkboxes). I've seen that before.

Comment: you'll also need to post your HTML form in your question. There may be something in there that isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways of doing this.

```
$email_to = "jhewitt@amleo.com,some@other.com,yet@another.net";

$email_to = 'Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
```

If you need to add emails as CC or BCC, add the following part in the variable you use as for your header :

```
$headers .= "CC: sombodyelse@noplace.com".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "BCC: hidden@special.com".PHP_EOL;
```

Source: [PHP form send email to multiple recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708997/php-form-send-email-to-multiple-recipients)

Also check here: [Example #1 Sending mail.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-examples)

Comment: That's not what I want... Since what I'm saying is that the user INPUTS the email address in a textbox THEMSELVES... not sent to a specific email address(es) every time you submit the form.

Comment: This is just a hint from which you can take an idea and proceed further. As you are saying that 'user INPUTS the email address in a textbox', you can mention a help near to textbox that please enter comma separated email ids for multiple or something like that or even there is a option to post-process the textbox data once you receive that in $_POST['emails']

Comment: Also what I was trying to say is that separating emails with comma's doesn't work.

Comment: Which is what I'm needing help with haha

Comment: @ryan-denton do you want an array for email as dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $email=$_POST['email'];   // write multiple emails with comma's    
 $emails=explode(',', $email); // explode email with comma's
     foreach($emails as $one_email)
     {
         $touser=$one_email;
            $subjectAdmin= "subject";
            $headersAdmin = "From: noreply@talentswype.com\r\n";
            $headersAdmin .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $messageuser ='msg here'; 
     $emailSenduser = mail($touser,$subjectAdmin,$messageuser,$headersAdmin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write one mail function per email.

```
mail('example1@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
mail('example2@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
mail('example3@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
mail('example4@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
mail('example5@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
```

or

```
foreach($mail as $mails ){
     mail($mail, 'My Subject', $message);
}
```