# Multiple recipients email php

Tags: php, email

How do I send to multiple recipients in php?
I only have one input field for the user to input all the recipients. The code already has a javascript which creates tags and autofill. The code only sends to the first input. 
Here is the code:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$deptm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dep_ID = ".$userRow['department_id']."");
$deptment = mysql_fetch_array($deptm);

if(isset($_POST['send-btn']))
{
 $recipient = $_POST['TO'];
 $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE faculty_number='$recipient'");
 $rec = mysql_fetch_array($check);
 if($userRow['position'] == 'Department Head')
 {
  if($rec['position'] != 'Dean' && $rec['position'] != 'Faculty Secretary')
  {
   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $indicator = $_POST['indicator'];
   $counter = $_POST['typ_cnt'];
   $date = date('M-j');
   /*$cnt=array();
   $cnt=count($_POST['department']);
   for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
   {
    $recipient=$_POST['department'][$i];*/
    if($del=mysql_query("INSERT INTO memo(memo_date, iso, memo_subject, content, memo_sender) VALUES ('$date', 'UST:".$indicator." - ".$counter."/AY 2015-2016', '$subject','$message','".$userRow['faculty_number']."')"))
    {
     $getID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memo ORDER BY memo_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
     $id = mysql_fetch_array($getID);
     if($recipient=mysql_query("INSERT INTO recipients(id,type,iso,memo_sender,recipient_num,read_status,read_timestamp,acknowledgement,ack_timestamp,delete_status) VALUES ('".$id['memo_ID']."','memo','UST:".$indicator." - ".$counter."/AY 2015-2016','".$userRow['faculty_number']."', '$recipient', 'unread', '---', 'Not Acknowledged', '---', 'active')"))
     {
       ?>
       <script>alert('Memo Sent');</script>
       <?php
     }
     else{
     ?>
      <script>alert('Failed');</script>
     <?php
    }
    }
    else{
    ?>
     <script>alert('Failed');</script>
    <?php
    }
   //}
  }else{
   ?>
   <script>alert('Your recipient is not allowed');</script>
   <?php
  }
 }else if($userRow['position'] == 'Dean')
 {
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $indicator = $_POST['indicator'];
   $counter = $_POST['typ_cnt'];
   $date = date('M-j');
   /*$cnt=array();
   $cnt=count($_POST['department']);
   for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
   {
    $recipient=$_POST['department'][$i];*/
    if($del=mysql_query("INSERT INTO memo(memo_date, iso, memo_subject, content, memo_sender) VALUES ('$date', 'UST:".$indicator." - ".$counter."/AY 2015-2016', '$subject','$message','".$userRow['faculty_number']."')"))
    {
     $getID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memo ORDER BY memo_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
     $id = mysql_fetch_array($getID);
     if($recipient=mysql_query("INSERT INTO recipients(id,type,iso,memo_sender,recipient_num,read_status,read_timestamp,acknowledgement,ack_timestamp,delete_status) VALUES ('".$id['memo_ID']."','memo','UST:".$indicator." - ".$counter."/AY 2015-2016','".$userRow['faculty_number']."', '$recipient', 'unread', '---', 'Not Acknowledged', '---', 'active')"))
     {
       ?>
       <script>alert('Memo Sent');</script>
       <?php
     }
     else{
     ?>
      <script>alert('Failed');</script>
     <?php
    }
    }
    else{
    ?>
     <script>alert('Failed');</script>
    <?php
    }
   //}
 }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <meta content="" name="description">
 <meta content="" name="author">

 <title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['position']; ?></title>
 <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
 <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel=
 "stylesheet"><!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
 <link href="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel=
 "stylesheet"><!-- Timeline CSS -->
 <link href="dist/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Custom CSS -->
 <link href="dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
 <link href="bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Custom Fonts -->
 <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel=
 "stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!-- Bootstrap styling for Typeahead -->
    <link href="dist/css/tokenfield-typeahead.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Tokenfield CSS -->
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Docs CSS -->
    <link href="docs-assets/css/pygments-manni.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="docs-assets/css/docs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 <script src="sendmemo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('department[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Navigation -->


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style=
  "margin-bottom: 0">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
    data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class=
    "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class=
    "icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class=
    "icon-bar"></span></button> <a class="navbar-brand" href=
    "index.html">UNIVERSITY OF SANTO TOMAS - FACULTY OF MEDICINE
    DOCUMENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</a>
   </div>
   <!-- /.navbar-header -->


   <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=
     "#"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> <i class=
     "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
      <li>
       <a href="#">
       <div>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i> New
        Message <span class=
        "pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes
        ago</span>
       </div></a>
      </li>


      <li class="divider">
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="#">
       <div>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> New
        Message <span class=
        "pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes
        ago</span>
       </div></a>
      </li>


      <li class="divider">
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="#">
       <div>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> New
        Message <span class=
        "pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes
        ago</span>
       </div></a>
      </li>


      <li class="divider">
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="#">
       <div>
        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Message
        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4
        minutes ago</span>
       </div></a>
      </li>


      <li class="divider">
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="#">
       <div>
        <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server
        Rebooted <span class=
        "pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes
        ago</span>
       </div></a>
      </li>


      <li class="divider">
      </li>


      <li>
       <a class="text-center" href="#"><strong>See All
       Notifications</strong> <i class=
       "fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
    </li>
    <!-- /.dropdown -->


    <li class="dropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=
     ""><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
     <?php echo $userRow['first_name'];?>&nbsp;<?php echo $userRow['middle_name'];?>&nbsp;<?php echo $userRow['last_name'];?>
     <b class="caret"></b></a>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
       <a><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
       <?php echo $userRow['position'];?></a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="divider">
      </li>

      <li>
       <a href="changepass.php"><i class=
       "fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>&nbsp;Change Password</a>
      </li>

      <li class="divider">
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="logout.php?logout"><i class=
       "fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- /.dropdown -->
   </ul>


   <div class="navbar-default sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
      <li>
       <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['home']?>"><i class=
       "fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Home</a>
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="sendmemo.php"><i class=
       "fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i> Send Memo</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a href="index.html"><i class=
       "fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Reports<span class=
       "fa arrow"></span></a>

       <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
         <a href="reports.php">List of
         Acknowledgement</a>
        </li>


        <li>
         <a href="index.html">Semestral Compliance
         Report</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
       <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="calendar.php"><i class=
       "fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Calendar</a>
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="inbox.php"><i class=
       "fa fa-inbox fa-fw"></i> Inbox</a>
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="sent.php"><i class=
       "fa fa-send-o fa-fw"></i> Sent</a>
      </li>


      <li>
       <a href="allfiles.php"><i class=
       "fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> All Files</a>
      </li>
      
      <?php
      if($userRow['position'] = 'Dean' && $userRow['position'] = 'Faculty Secretary')
      { ?>
       <li>
       <a href="deanfolder.php"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Folders</a>
       </li>
       <?php
      }else if($userRow['position'] = 'Department Head')
      { ?>
       <li>
       <a href="departmentfolder.php"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Folders</a>
       </li>
       <?php
      }else if($userRow['position'] = 'Faculty')
      { ?>
       <li>
       <a href="facultyfolder.php"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Folders</a>
       </li>
       <?php
      }
      ?>

      <li>
       <a href="upload.php"><i class=
       "fa  fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Upload Document</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
  </nav>


  <div id="page-wrapper">
  
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
  <h2 class="text-center">Send Memo</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#memo">Memo</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#letter">Letter</a></li>
  </ul>
<?php
  switch($userRow['position'])
  {
   case 'Dean': $ind="A001-001";
      break;
   case 'Faculty Secretary': $ind="A002-002";
      break;
   case 'Department Head': $ind="A003-003";
      break;
  }
  
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from recipients WHERE memo_sender=".$userRow['faculty_number']);
  $cntr=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $cnt = $cntr['total']+1;
  
  $curYr = date('Y');
 ?>
  <div class="tab-content">
  
    <div id="memo" class="tab-pane fade in active">
 <form method="post">
      <div class="form-inline" role="form" ><br>
       <label>ISO:</label>
         <div class="form-group">
         <label>UST:</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="indicator" value="<?php echo $ind;?>" style="width:90px;"
          type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>-</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="typ_cnt" value="ME<?php echo $cnt;?>" style="width:60px;">
            <label>/AY <?php echo $curYr;?> - <?php echo date('Y',strtotime('+1 year'));?> </label>
         </div>
       </div><br>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label>TO:</label>
         <div class="input-group">
                                    <input name="TO" type="textbox" class="form-control" id="tokenfield-typeahead" value="
         <?php
         if(isset($_POST['select-btn']))
         {
          $cnt=array();
          $cnt=count($_POST['department']);
          for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
          {
           $del_id=$_POST['department'][$i];
           echo $del_id.",";
          }
         }
         ?> "/>    
         <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" value="Departments" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Department</button>
         </span>
            </div>
         </div>
        
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subj">SUBJECT:</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="subject"
          type="text">
         </div>
         <br>


         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Message:</label> 

          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
         </div>   
        <button  type="submit" name="send-btn" class="btn btn-warning">Send</button>         
        </form>
        
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
           <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Departments</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             
           <form method="post" action="sendmemo.php">   
           <div class="form-group">
          <?php
           $deptlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM departments");
           while($dept = mysql_fetch_array($deptlist))
           {
           echo "<div class='checkbox'>";
                                               echo "<label>";
                                                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='department[]' value='".$dept['department_name']."' >" . $dept['department_name']; 
                                               echo "</label>";
                                            echo "</div>";
           }
          ?> 
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="submit" name="select-btn" class="btn btn-warning">Select</button>
           </div>
                                            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="letter" class="tab-pane fade">
<form method="post">
      <div class="form-inline" role="form" ><br>
       <label>ISO:</label>
         <div class="form-group">
         <label>UST:</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="indicator" value="<?php echo $ind;?>" style="width:90px;"
          type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>-</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="typ_cnt" value="ME<?php echo $cnt;?>" style="width:60px;">
            <label>/AY <?php echo $curYr;?> - <?php echo date('Y',strtotime('+1 year'));?> </label>
         </div>
       </div><br>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label>TO:</label>
         <div class="input-group">
         <input name="TO" type="textbox" class="form-control">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" value="Departments" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Department</button>
         </span>
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
           <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Departments</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             
           <div class="form-group">
          <?php
           $deptlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM departments");
           while($dept = mysql_fetch_array($deptlist))
           {
           $dept_head = mysql_query("SELECT faculty_number FROM user WHERE position='Department Head' AND department_id='".$dept['dep_ID']."'");
           echo "<div class='checkbox'>";
                                               echo "<label>";
                                                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='department[]' value='$dept_head' >" . $dept['department_name']; 
                                               echo "</label>";
                                            echo "</div>";
           }
          ?> 
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Select</button>
           </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
         </div>


         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subj">SUBJECT:</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="subject" type="text">
         </div>
         <br>


         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Message:</label> 

          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
         </div>   
        <button  type="submit" name="send-btn" class="btn btn-danger">Send</button>         
        </form>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
   </div>


 
 <!-- /#wrapper -->
 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script> <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src="dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs-assets/js/scrollspy.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs-assets/js/affix.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs-assets/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script>
  var engine = new Bloodhound({
  <!--local: [{value: 'red'}, {value: 'blue'}, {value: 'green'} , {value: 'yellow'}, {value: 'violet'}, {value: 'brown'}, {value: 'purple'}, {value: 'black'}, {value: 'white'}, {value: 'jerome'}],
  local: [<?php $suggest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
  while($info = mysql_fetch_array($suggest))
  {
   echo "{value: '".$info['faculty_number']." (".$info['last_name'].", ".$info['first_name'].")'},";
  }
  ?>],
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
  return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
  },
   queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
  });

  engine.initialize();

  $('#tokenfield-typeahead').tokenfield({
  typeahead: [null, { source: engine.ttAdapter() }]
  });
    </script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you should do to send to a couple recipients is:

```
$message = "Email Body goes here";
$to = $recepient1.",".$recepient2.",".$recepient3; 
$subject = 'Some Subject';
$from = $sender_email;
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: ' . $to . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't post your (full) email code, only a part that puts some data in a database.

Look at this post:

[PHP form send email to multiple recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708997/php-form-send-email-to-multiple-recipients)

If you can't implement it yourself, update your question with your full email code so i can do it for you.

**Edit:**
I implemented this snippet; you have to enter the recipients with a , (comma + space) between them in the old html form field;

```
<?php
$recipient = "recipienta, recipientb";
$recipients =  explode(", ",$recipient);    
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) { 
    echo $recipient;
}
?>
```

Here is the relevant part of your code with the snippet implemented, i don't have all your dependencies so i couldn't test it but it should work, if it doesn't just let me know your problem and i'll fix it <3;

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$deptm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dep_ID = ".$userRow['department_id']."");
$deptment = mysql_fetch_array($deptm);

if(isset($_POST['send-btn']))
{
    $recipient = $_POST['TO'];
    $recipients =  explode(", ",$recipient);   
    foreach ($recipients as $recipient) { 

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE faculty_number='$recipient'");
        $rec = mysql_fetch_array($check);
        if($userRow['position'] == 'Department Head')
        {
            if($rec['position'] != 'Dean' && $rec['position'] != 'Faculty Secretary')
            {
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $indicator = $_POST['indicator'];
                $counter = $_POST['typ_cnt'];
                $date = date('M-j');
                /*$cnt=array();
                $cnt=count($_POST['department']);
                for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
                {
                    $recipient=$_POST['department'][$i];*/
                    if($del=mysql_query("INSERT INTO memo(memo_date, iso, memo_subject, content, memo_sender) VALUES ('$date', 'UST:".$indicator." - ".$counter."/AY 2015-2016', '$subject','$message','".$userRow['faculty_number']."')"))
                    {
                        $getID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memo ORDER BY memo_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
                        $id = mysql_fetch_array($getID);
                        if($recipient=mysql_query("INSERT INTO recipients(id,type,iso,memo_sender,recipient_num,read_status,read_timestamp,acknowledgement,ack_timestamp,delete_status) VALUES ('".$id['memo_ID']."','memo','UST:".$indicator." - ".$counter."/AY 2015-2016','".$userRow['faculty_number']."', '$recipient', 'unread', '---', 'Not Acknowledged', '---', 'active')"))
                        {
                                ?>
                                <script>alert('Memo Sent');</script>
                                <?php
                        }
                        else{
                        ?>
                            <script>alert('Failed');</script>
                        <?php
                    }
                    }
                    else{
                    ?>
                        <script>alert('Failed');</script>
                    <?php
                    }
                //}
            }else{
                ?>
                <script>alert('Your recipient is not allowed');</script>
                <?php
            }
        }else if($userRow['position'] == 'Dean')
        {
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $indicator = $_POST['indicator'];
                $counter = $_POST['typ_cnt'];
                $date = date('M-j');
                /*$cnt=array();
                $cnt=count($_POST['department']);
                for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
                {
                    $recipient=$_POST['department'][$i];*/
                    if($del=mysql_query("INSERT INTO memo(memo_date, iso, memo_subject, content, memo_sender) VALUES ('$date', 'UST:".$indicator." - ".$counter."/AY 2015-2016', '$subject','$message','".$userRow['faculty_number']."')"))
                    {
                        $getID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memo ORDER BY memo_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
                        $id = mysql_fetch_array($getID);
                        if($recipient=mysql_query("INSERT INTO recipients(id,type,iso,memo_sender,recipient_num,read_status,read_timestamp,acknowledgement,ack_timestamp,delete_status) VALUES ('".$id['memo_ID']."','memo','UST:".$indicator." - ".$counter."/AY 2015-2016','".$userRow['faculty_number']."', '$recipient', 'unread', '---', 'Not Acknowledged', '---', 'active')"))
                        {
                                ?>
                                <script>alert('Memo Sent');</script>
                                <?php
                        }
                        else{
                        ?>
                            <script>alert('Failed');</script>
                        <?php
                    }
                    }
                    else{
                    ?>
                        <script>alert('Failed');</script>
                    <?php
                    }
                //}
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have no idea why it is a down vite but once my reputation goes high, ill up it. Sorry.

Anyway it still doesnt work. No comma is showing :(