# Send email to selected users in database

Tags: php

Im building up a cron in which it will send an email to admins when my inventory is low. Right now, I am able to send this email to just one recipient only. Can someone please help me? I can't seem to get the logic out of it.

```
<?php

  $db_host = "dbhost";
  $db_username = "user";
  $db_password = "pass";

  $conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connect.');
  $db  = mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn) or die (mysql_error());

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT prod_count, restock_level, prod_code FROM inventory WHERE prod_count <= restock_level;");

  if ($result) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count = $row['prod_count'];
    $restocklvl = $row['restock_level'];

    if ($count <= $restocklvl) {
      $subject ="Low Inventory Notification";
      $recipient = "adminemail@email.com"; //Users from the database

      $msg = "Dear Admin, 

      Please check your inventory status. There are currently some items that are low on stock and needs to be replenished.

      *This is an automated message. Please do not reply.";
      mail($recipient, $subject, $msg);
    }
  } else {
    $msg = "An error occurred while checking inventory: " . mysql_error();
    mail($recipient, "Inventory check error", $msg);
  }
?>
```

Comment: you should keep array for recipient email ids and can loop over it to send emails using your mail function

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708997/php-form-send-email-to-multiple-recipients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this part to...

```
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $count = $row['prod_count'];
        $restocklvl = $row['restock_level'];
        if ($count <= $restocklvl) {
            $subject ="Low Inventory Notification";
            $recipient = "adminemail@email.com"; //Users from the database

            $msg = "Dear Admin, 

             Please check your inventory status. There are currently some items that are low on stock and needs to be replenished.

            *This is an automated message. Please do not reply.";
            mail($recipient, $subject, $msg);
        }

    }
}
```