# Send email from addresses stored in mysql database to multiple recipients

Tags: php, mysql

In the example below if I uncomment  $emailList then the email is sent. The echo from database shows "email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com"

If I keep only one address in the database it works too. Not sure if the comma between the address is causing the issue. I am not sure why the email is now being sent with info from the database for multiple addresses.

```
$emailId = mysql_query("Select * from email_group WHERE id = 1");
while($rowEmail = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailId))
{
$emailList = $rowEmail['email']; 
} 

// the message
$msg = "Test Message";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

echo $emailList;
//$emailList = "email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com";

// send email
mail($emailList,"Test Subject",$msg);
```

Comment: remove last comma from `$emailList = "email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com,";` and try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP form send email to multiple recipients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708997/php-form-send-email-to-multiple-recipients)

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because as far as I can see, each time your while loop is run through, your `$emailList` will be overwritten with the last email, and not contain the previous values from the loop.

Comment: yes, actual code. I have only one list of email address per id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
$emailId = mysql_query("Select * from email_group WHERE id = 1");

$emailList = [];
while($rowEmail = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailId))
{
$emailList[] = $rowEmail['email']; 
} 

// the message
$msg = "Test Message";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail(implode(", ", $emailList),"Test Subject",$msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using your code `$emailList = "email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com,";`

The problem is the last comma. Which puts an extra comma on the code like,

```
mail(email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com,,"Test Subject",$msg); 

// Which leads to an error.
```

So remove the last comma from the email string, using the code,

```
$emailList = rtrim($emailList, ",");
```

Now the `$emailList` is like,

```
$emailList = "email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com";
```

**Another Method**

Explode the email list and send one by one. Like,

```
$email_ids = explode(",",$emailList);

foreach($email_ids as $email){
  mail($email,"Test Subject",$msg); 
}
```

Comment: without using foreach, it is possible to send an email

Comment: @SantoshPillai remove last come from `$emailList = "email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com,";`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do just trim your email address, cause it has a comma at the end of the string. so try this.

```
$emailId = mysql_query("Select * from email_group WHERE id = 1");
while($rowEmail = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailId))
{
$emailList = $rowEmail['email']; 
} 

// the message
$msg = "Test Message";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

echo $emailList = rtrim($emailList, ",");
//$emailList = "email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com";

// send email
mail($emailList,"Test Subject",$msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$emailId = mysql_query("Select * from email_group WHERE id = 1");
while($rowEmail = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailId))
{
    $emailList[] = $rowEmail['email'];
}

// the message
$msg = "Test Message";
// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);    
if(!empty($emailList)) {
    $emails = implode(',',$emailList);
    // send email
    mail($emails,"Test Subject",$msg);
}
?>
```