# Want to send php mail() to two users at the same time using php variable

Tags: php, html, mailer

Am trying to use php to send email to two different users all at the same time from the user input information which i have convert into variables.

```
<?php
$shipperemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['shipperemail']);
$receiveremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['receiveremail']);
$receiveremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['receiveremail']);
$email_from = "valueHandlers@me.com";
    $email_to = ".$shipperemail.";
    $email_to = ".$receiveremail.";
    $email_subject = "Tracking Code"; 
    $email_message .= "Tracking Code: ".$consignmentno."\n";
    $email_message .= "Sender Name: ".$shippername."\n";
    $email_message .= "Receiver Name: ".$receivername."\n";
    $email_message .= "Expected date of delevery: ".$shipmentexpected."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".$comments."\n";
    $email_message .= "for more update, folow the link Http://valuehandlers.com/track";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>
```

but none of the variable is delvering the mail to the variables emails

Comment: Rationalization of the same variable `$email_to` means you are replacing old one.

Comment: there shouldn't be dots in the to/receiver variables `$email_to = ".$shipperemail.";
    $email_to = ".$receiveremail.";`; you're trying to concatenate but doing it wrong and that's why it's failing.

Comment: should `@mail` be only `mail` ?

Comment: and `$consignmentno` is unknown (probably somewhere else, no idea; probably irrelevant). Check for errors if none of those variables are getting through; you're not doing that.

Comment: *"should @ mail be only mail"* - The @ here @Joshi is just an error suppressor.

Comment: Further to what @Fred-ii- has said, this post might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708997/php-form-send-email-to-multiple-recipients

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- and all who comment