# php mailer | Add multiple recipients | WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a classified website, where users are able to publish whatever they want to sell or advertise from the front end. At the end of each published post, a client can get in touch with the seller by filling in a contact form. By default, the email goes to the publisher. The function $ contact_email, is the publisher's email address. However, I would like to add additional recipients.

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $emailTo = $contact_email;
        $subject = $subject;    
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $comments";
        $headers = 'From <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

        $emailSent = true;

}
```

This is a WordPress website. How can I modify this code to add that capability? I still want the original author, $contact_email, and site editor to receive a copy of the email sent from the contact form:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP form send email to multiple recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708997/php-form-send-email-to-multiple-recipients)

Answer (score 0):

You can take `to` address as an array and add another email address

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {

            $emailTo = array($contact_email,$contact_email2);
            $subject = $subject;    
            $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $comments";
            $headers = 'From <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

            wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

            $emailSent = true;

}
```

Here variable `$contact_email2` should contain email id of another recipient you want to have.

Comment: You can even add recipients in CC and BCC of headers